# Convergence Of Subsequence Of A Bounded Sequence

Tags: calculus

Prove that for every bounded sequence say $a_n$ there exists a subsequence which is convergent.
$$$$Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence. Now if $a_n$ converges then any of its subsequence converges, so let $a_n$ does not converge, then if we consider any $a_r$ for some $r$ we have for every $N$ there exists a $n$ such that $$|a_n-a_r|\geq \epsilon_0$$ for some $\epsilon_0$. So we have for every $N$ there exists a $n$ such that either $$1. a_n \geq a_r+\epsilon_0>a_r$$ or $$2. a_n \leq a_r+\epsilon_0<a_r$$ and also one these inequalities follows for infinitely many $n$.Now we consider the following two cases:
$$$$Case 1. For any subsequence $t_n$ of $a_n$ there exists a $t_w$ such that for infinitely many $n$ inequality $(1)$ follows. In this case let $b_n$ be any arbitrary subsequence of $a_n$ then there exists a $b_p$ such that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $b_n>b_p$, let us choose any one of them say $b_q$. Now consider a subsequence $d_n$ of $b_n$ such that $d_n>b_p$ for every $n$ whose first term is $b_q$ then again there exists a $d_s$ such that for infinitely many $n$ we have $d_n>d_s$, then again choose any one of them say $d_k$. Now we have $d_s>b_p$. Again we can repeat the same for $d_s$ by choosing a subsequence $p_n$ of $d_n$ such that $p_n>d_s$ whose first term is $d_k$.Again for $p_n$ there exists some $p_0$ sich that for infinitely many $n$ we have $p_n>p_0$ . Amd also we have $p_0>d_s>b_p$. And hence we can create an increasing subsequence of $a_n$ and as this subsequence is bounded so it is convergent.
$$$$Case 2. There exists a subsequence $b_n$ of the sequence $a_n$ such that for every $r$ the inequality $(2)$ follows for infinitely many $n$ and hence in the subsequence $b_n$ for every $r$ we can find some $s>r$ such that $a_r>a_s$ and similarly for $a_s$ we can find some $t>s$ such that $a_t<a_s$ and processing in this way we can create a decreasing subsequence of the sequence $a_n$ and as this subsequence is bounded so it is convergent.
$$$$Can Someone Plz Help me With This Proof??

Comment: I don't think your proof works, the first statement is itself wrong :(

Comment: Which statement you are talking about??

Comment: @Shamim What happened ??

Comment: I am sorry.....

Comment: @Shamim What happened? Is My Proof Correct Or Not ??